# Revit Option Bar

Tags: revit, revit-api

I apologize if this has been asked before, but my search didn't turn up anything on this topic.

Is there a way to show options in the Options Bar in Revit 2016 while prompting the user to select an object (in my case, a Ceiling in a space)?

For example, when using the built-in array command the following shows up on the option bar for user feedback and input:

[image: Image of Array Option Bar]
*[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOiSm.png)*

How do I do something like this in my code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been looking in the Revit API documentation and online. I have successfully created a new tab in the ribbon, and placed working buttons in it. I have successfully created form(s) that have labels, text boxes, combo boxes etc. What I want is to place these (labels, text boxes, combo boxes, checkboxes etc.) in the Revit "Option Bar". Not sure if there is a way?

Comment: don't believe there is an API for this, the Application.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.PickObject() method don't have such a control/option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for that, unfortunately. There is no a lot of support in Revit for all things related to the user interface. And the option bar is superseded by contextual tabs, so I don't think there will be API for that in the future (there is also no support for contextual tabs at the moment).

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thank you for the confirmation.